# Image gets disappeared in the vertical scrollpane view port

Tags: java, image, swing, scrollpane

duke.png -> [image: duke.png]

arrowToLeft.gif -> [image: arrowToKeft]

arrowToRight.gif -> [image]

I need a UI where I want to depict a network device's graphical representation in Swing. For this, I am just loading multiple images and overlap them one by one to show the current state of the device. I have to support zooming for this view. The zoom code looks like this.

```
public class LayeredPaneTest{
        private JLayeredPane layeredPane;
        private JScrollPane scrollPane;
        private static double MIN_ZOOM_VALUE = 0.60; // 1.0;
        private static double MAX_ZOOM_VALUE = 2.0;
        private static final int LAYER1 = 0;
        private static final int LAYER2 = 1;
        private static final int LAYER3 = 3;
        private double scaleFactor = 1.0;
        private JInternalFrame internalFrame =
            new JInternalFrame("LayeredPaneTest",false, false, false, false);

        public LayeredPaneTest(){
             loadView();
        }

        public JInternalFrame getView(){
             return internalFrame;
        }

        private void loadView(){
            ((javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicInternalFrameUI)internalFrame.getUI())
               .setNorthPane(null);
            internalFrame.setBorder(null);      
            internalFrame.getContentPane().add(buildCenterPane());      
            internalFrame.setSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
            internalFrame.setLocation(0, 0);
            internalFrame.setResizable(false);
            internalFrame.setVisible(true);
        }

        private JPanel buildCenterPane(){
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
            Position shelfPosition = new Position(0,0,200,200);
            setLayeredPaneSize(shelfPosition);
            JLabel label = getImageLabel(getImage("duke.png"),
                new  Position(0,0,100,100));        
            layeredPane.add(label, Integer.valueOf(LAYER1));        
            label = getImageLabel(getImage("arrowToLeft.gif"),
                new Position(100,100,50,50));       
            layeredPane.add(label, Integer.valueOf(LAYER2));
            label = getImageLabel(getImage("arrowToRight.gif"),
                new Position(50,50,50,50));     
            layeredPane.add(label, Integer.valueOf(LAYER3));        
            scrollPane = new JScrollPane(layeredPane);      
            panel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            panel.add(getSliderPane(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);     
            return panel;
        }

        private Image getImage(String key){
    InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(key);
    try {
        return ImageIO.read(is);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
        }

        private void setLayeredPaneSize(Position shelfPosition){
            int width = (int)(shelfPosition.getWidth() * scaleFactor + 10);
            int height = (int)(shelfPosition.getHeight() * scaleFactor + 10);
            layeredPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width,height));
        }

        public void zoom(double factor){
            if (factor < MIN_ZOOM_VALUE)
                factor = MIN_ZOOM_VALUE;
            else if (factor > MAX_ZOOM_VALUE)
                factor = MAX_ZOOM_VALUE;
            scaleFactor = factor;
            Position shelfPosition = new Position(0,0,200,200);
            setLayeredPaneSize(shelfPosition);        
            scrollPane.getViewport().repaint();
            scrollPane.repaint();        
            scrollPane.getViewport().revalidate();
            scrollPane.revalidate();
        }

        private JLabel getImageLabel(Image image, Position position) {
            position = position.moveInRatio(scaleFactor);
            ImageLabel label = new ImageLabel(new ImageIcon(image), position);
            label.setOpaque(false);
            label.setBounds(position.getLeft(),  
                position.getTop(),position.getWidth(),position.getHeight());
            return label;
        }

        private JPanel getSliderPane(){
            JPanel outer = new JPanel();
            outer.setLayout(new FlowLayout());      
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            final JSlider slider = new JSlider((int) (MIN_ZOOM_VALUE * 100),
                (int) (MAX_ZOOM_VALUE * 100), 100);
            slider.setMajorTickSpacing(1);
            slider.setMinorTickSpacing(1);
            double sliderValue = scaleFactor * 100.0;
            slider.setValue((int) sliderValue);
            slider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {         
        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
            scaleFactor = slider.getValue() / 100.0;
            zoom(scaleFactor);

        }
    });
            panel.add(slider, BorderLayout.CENTER);        
            outer.add(panel);
            return outer;
        }

        public static void main(String...strings){
           JFrame frame = new JFrame("FrameDemo");
           frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
           frame.getContentPane().add(new LayeredPaneTest().getView(), 
               BorderLayout.CENTER);
           frame.pack();
           frame.setVisible(true);
        }

        static class Position{
           private final int left,top,width,height;

           Position(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2){
               this.left = x1;
               this.top = y1;
               this.width = x2;
               this.height = y2;
               }

               public int getLeft() {
           return left;
       }

       public int getTop() {
           return top;
       }

       public int getWidth() {
           return width;
       }

       public int getHeight() {
           return height;
       }    
        }

        private class ImageLabel extends JLabel{
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 6152144095443433296L;
            private ImageIcon image;
            private Position position;

            public ImageLabel(ImageIcon image, Position position){
            super(image);
            this.image = image;
            this.position = position;
            }

            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            int newX = (int)(position.getLeft() * scaleFactor);
            int newY = (int)(position.getTop() * scaleFactor);          
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
            int newW = (int)(position.getWidth() * scaleFactor);
            int newH = (int)(position.getHeight() * scaleFactor);
            setBounds(newX, newY, newW, newH);
            g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, 
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2.drawImage(image.getImage(), 0, 0, newW, newH, null);
            }
        }

}
```

But the problem here is, when I zoom in once and zoom out, some of the images disappear. Any idea why it behaves like this?

Following are the steps to reproduce the bug;
  a. Drag the slider bar to the maximum,
  b. Witness the image being expanded to maximum and the scroll bar is introduced,
  c. Now few portion of the image is hidden,
  d. Now drag the slider bar to minimum.
  e. The hidden portion of the image disappears.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Answer (score 1):

You do not honor the *paint chain* by calling `super.XXX` implementation of overridden `paintComponent` method like so:

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics grphcs) {
    super.paintComponent(grphcs);

    //do the rest of the painting here
}
```

As [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent%28java.awt.Graphics%29) clearly state:

> if you do not invoker super's implementation you must honor the opaque
>   property, that is if this component is opaque, you must completely
>   fill in the background in a non-opaque color. If you do not honor the
>   opaque property you will likely see visual artifacts.

Also note the `@Override` annotation to make sure I am overriding the correct method, and by default `paintComponent` is `protected` keep it that way as you dont want to *expose* this method to other classes they should use `repaint()`

Comment: Still not working after the changes you have mentioned. Updated the question with SSCCE.